# What is the probability that the number of rolls required to obtain two different faces on a fair die is $4$?

Tags: probability

An individual continues to roll a fair die till he/she has obtained at least two different faces. What is the probability that the total number of rolls required to satisfy the objective is 4?

I tried this:

Let $X$ be the number of rolls required to satisfy the objective.
\begin{align*}
P(X=2) & = 1/6\\
P(X=3) & = 5/6 \cdot 1/6\\
P(X=4) & = 5/6 \cdot 5/6 \cdot  1/6 = (25/216)
\end{align*}

Comment: what have you tried? It would help us in guiding you.

Comment: Hint: the first roll is irrelevant to the probability.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: On this forum, you are required  to first show what you have tried, and where you are stuck to aptly  address your difficulties.

Comment: Your attempt is close, but you've made a mistake. Can you say where your $\frac56$ and $\frac16$ come from?

Comment: $1\over6$ probability that roll 2 is same number, $1\over6$ probability that roll 3 is same number, $5\over6$ probability that roll 4 is different.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to find the probability that total number of rolls required to get two different faces is $4$.  For this to occur, the first three rolls must produce the same number, while the fourth roll must produce a different number from the first three.  The first roll can be anything.  The second roll must be the same as the first, which occurs with probability $1/6$.  The third roll must also be the same as the first, which occurs with probability $1/6$.  The fourth roll must be different from the first, which occurs with probability $5/6$.  Hence,
$$\Pr(X = 4) = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} = \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{5}{6}\right) = \frac{5}{216}$$
Your answer for $\Pr(X = 3)$ is correct.  Your answer for $\Pr(X = 2)$ should be $5/6$ since the first roll can be anything and the second roll must be different from the first, which gives
$$\Pr(X = 2) = 1 \cdot \frac{5}{6} = \frac{5}{6}$$

Let's look at the general case.  Say we wish to find the probability that the total number of rolls required to obtain two different faces is $n$.  The first roll can be anything.  The next $n - 2$ rolls must be the same as the first roll, which occurs with probability $(1/6)^{n - 2}$.  The $n$th roll must be different from the first roll, which occurs with probability $5/6$.  Hence,
$$\Pr(X = n) = 1 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n - 2}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n - 2}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)$$
Our formula yields
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X = 2) & = \frac{5}{6}\\
\Pr(X = 3) & = \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{5}{6}\right) = \frac{5}{36}\\
\Pr(X = 4) & = \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{5}{6}\right) = \frac{5}{216}
\end{align*}

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \Pr(X = n) & = \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n - 2}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\\
& = \frac{5}{6}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n - 2}\\
& = \frac{5}{6}\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{m - 1} && \text{(set $m = n - 1$)}\\
& = \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{6}}\\
& = \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{\frac{5}{6}}\\
& = \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{6}{5}\\
& = 1
\end{align*}
as required.